# How to increment a sequential identifier in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have an Invoice table in dynamodb with hash-sort combo key. The hash is a uuid "tenantId" and the sort is a uuid named "id" for the invoice. However I have a field called "InvoiceNumber" which is the human readable sequential identifier for the invoices.

What is the best/optimal way to increment the InvoiceNumber when I create a new record while ensuring uniqueness and avoid race conditions?

**Edit:** Uniqueness would need to be enforced for each hash or tenant but not across the table.

Comment: Is the `InvoiceNumber` unique within each `tenantId` or global? Also, does any of your items ever get deleted?

Comment: For now they can be deleted but if it helps the process I can archive them instead. As for uniqueness. It would need to be unique within the same hash (tenantId) but not across the entire table.

Comment: @Andre.IDK any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [Atomic Counter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters) example. It is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Doesn't atomic value work on an existing record? For example vote = vote + 1. In my case I'm looking to grab the last invoice number and increase it by one for the new record while being mindful of race conditions.

Comment: > An atomic counter would not be appropriate where overcounting or undercounting can't be tolerated (for example, in a banking application).